# Bootstrap popover is showing the same text in all popups

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have 5 different popups with different texts but all of the are showing the same text. Any help? Thanks.

```
<label class="radio span1">
        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="option1">Level 1 
            <a href="#" rel="popover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" id="level1">?</a>
            <div id="acuty-level" class="popover">Level 1</div>
    </label>

    $('[rel=popover]').popover({
      html: true,
      content: function () {
       return $('#acuty-level').html();
     }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/824uJ/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have duplicate id issue. Html must not contain more than one element with the same id.

There are multiple elements with id `acuty-level`. Just remove the ids or have unique ids. 
Your id selector will always fetch only the first element with the id `acuty-level` that is present in DOM, hence you see this behavior.

`<div id="acuty-level" class="popover">Level 1</div>`

In the script use the `this` context inside the content function to get the popover which is a sibling and you should have your issue fixed.

#### Script

```
$('[rel=popover]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        return $(this).siblings('.popover').html();
    }
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W5gYx/)

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: @PSL has a much more elegant solution

you are using `id="acuty-level"` for all popovers. ID should only be used once in a page. All the other instances will be ignored. Give each popup it's own specific ID, like so:

HTML:

```
<label class="radio span1">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="option1">Level 1 
                <a href="#" rel="popover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" id="level1">?</a>
                <div class="acuty-level1" class="popover">Level 1</div>
        </label>
```

Javascript part:

```
$('[rel=popover]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        return $('#acuty-level1').html();
    }
});
```

Repeat for all other popovers

Comment: I understand but I assigned a different id and still I'm having the same issue: http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/824uJ/7/

Comment: @Labanino Why you need to select it with id itself. You can use diff ids, but use class to select it. See my answer and example.

Comment: @Labanino Based on your sample it should be http://jsfiddle.net/jY2q4/, but its a maintenance headache to add id in the selection when you have to add another similar element.

Comment: PSL, yours is very nice but take a look at this one, it's not showing a section of the html: http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/3etXM/

Comment: @Labanino Your selector is wrong as your html structure changes from whats in your actual question. YOu need to fix the selector too. See this http://jsfiddle.net/RhDYG/. BTW use AtTheRatePSL so that i get notification :)

Comment: @PSL the issue I'm having now is that in my code I have both scenarios  . The one with radios is working fine but the popover with html doesn't. http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/W5gYx/2/

Comment: @Labanino Try change your markup for consistency like this . http://jsfiddle.net/BdvYS/ else you can use both the condition to see if `popover` is available in the sibling level if not find it at the parent next level.